# Admin 201 Certification

Tags: adm201

I am looking to give salesforce 201 Admin certification but while registering in webassessor i dont see any certification with name 201. Has it been decomissioned?

Answer (score 1):

> Has it been decomissioned?

Yes and no. Certifications have changed slightly, as of last year (I think!), but the 201 is now the Certified Administrator exam.

Other changes, for instance, are:

- 301 is now Certified Advanced Administrator
- 401 is now Custom App Builder
- 501 is now Platform Developer II

They also introduced a new exam, 450, which is Platform Developer I.

[image]